# How to remove first part of url in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to remove te first part of the url in PHP. Example:

```
http://www.domain.com/sales
http://otherdomain.org/myfolder/seconddir
/directory
```

must be:

```
/sales
/myfolder/seconddir
/directory
```

Because the url in dynamic, I think I have to do this with preg replace, but I don't know how.. And sometimes the url is already removed (see last example).
How to do this?

Comment: Where are these URLs coming from?

Comment: From an input form.. But the method below with parse_url worked for me! Thanks.

Comment: @user735795: Then you chould accept it (click the checkmark next to the most helpful answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a built in php function for this [parse_url](http://docs.php.net/parse_url).

From the linked website:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
/path
```

Comment: Note this will not work for URLs that does not contain scheme for ex. www.otherdomain.org/myfolder/seconddir

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://otherdomain.org/myfolder/seconddir';
$urlParts = parse_url($url);

print_r($urlParts);
```

And have a look at:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 2):

you could use [path info](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```
<?php
print_r(pathinfo("http://www.domain.com/sales"));
print_r(pathinfo("http://otherdomain.org/myfolder/seconddir"));
print_r(pathinfo("/directory"));
?>
```

the output:

```
Array
(
    [dirname] => http://www.domain.com
    [basename] => sales
    [filename] => sales
)
Array
(
    [dirname] => http://otherdomain.org/myfolder
    [basename] => seconddir
    [filename] => seconddir
)
Array
(
    [dirname] => /
    [basename] => directory
    [filename] => directory
)
```

good luck!