# PHP Regex to Remove http:// from string

Tags: php, regex

I have full URLs as strings, but I want to remove the http:// at the beginning of the string to display the URL nicely (ex: www.google.com instead of http://www.google.com)

Can someone help?

Comment: Why do you need a regex?  Why not just remove the first 7 characters?

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875085/php-remove-http-from-link-title

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: It can be 8 characters as well with `https://`

Comment: If you don't need to use regex, don't.  `str_replace` is faster than regex, and easier to read for other people looking at your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove http from variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7293799/), [Parsing Domain From URL In PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/276516/), [How to remove first part of url in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5867310/).

Comment: @VettelS: not appreciably faster. If just 'http:' scheme needs to be handled, then `str_replace` is preferabel, but if both 'http:' and 'https:' schemes need to be covered, then regex approach is likely faster & more readable. '%^https?://%' isn't that difficult to read.

Comment: @outis How do you guys know which function or library is faster? Where do you get those benchmarks or what procedure do you follow to weigh the speed of a code, library or function? I'm fascinated, and curious!

Answer (score 152, accepted):

```
$str = 'http://www.google.com';
$str = preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', $str);
echo $str; // www.google.com
```

That will work for both `http://` and `https://`

Comment: Coming from someone who doesn't know a whole lot about regex this was one of the easiest to understand and implement solutions to this problem, thanks a bunch.

Comment: if http is uppercase what will be the changes in regex? @sarfraz

Comment: how to delete www too?

Answer (score 24):

You don't need regular expression at all. Use [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) instead.

```
str_replace('http://', '', $subject);
str_replace('https://', '', $subject);
```

Combined into a single operation as follows:

```
str_replace(array('http://','https://'), '', $urlString);
```

Comment: This will also strip out any subsequent matches of http(s)://, which may not be a problem - but it could be. For example if it is used in a query string without proper urlencoding

Answer (score 20):

Better use this:

```
$url = parse_url($url);  
$url = $url['host'];

echo $url;
```

Simpler and works for `http://` `https://` `ftp://` and almost all prefixes.

Comment: Except that it will throw away any path and query information as well as the transport protocol. So while it works successfully on the OPs example, it's not actually the correct answer for their question.

Comment: @piersb I can't fully agree with you on this. The code successfully delivers the result Casey was looking for. Besides, it was written to serve one purpose. If you want to show path or query information you can certainly do so (http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). However, I've found one problem with the code. If we try to parse the url without specifying the protocol, it shows an error and that's something I'm annoyed with right now :/

Answer (score 4):

Why not use [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) instead?

Answer (score 3):

To remove http://domain ( or https ) and to get the path:

```
   $str = preg_replace('#^https?\:\/\/([\w*\.]*)#', '', $str);
   echo $str;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using RegEx:

```
preg_match( "/^(https?:\/\/)?(.+)$/", $input, $matches );
$url = $matches[0][2];
```

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, I'd add a `s?` after the http.  And yeah, I know it wasn't in his question . . . :))

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I think that str_replace() and substr() are faster and cleaner than regex. Here is a safe fast function for it. It's easy to see exactly what it does. Note: return substr($url, 7) and substr($url, 8), if you also want to remove the //.

```
// slash-slash protocol remove https:// or http:// and leave // - if it's not a string starting with https:// or http:// return whatever was passed in
function universal_http_https_protocol($url) {  
  // Breakout - give back bad passed in value
  if (empty($url) || !is_string($url)) {
    return $url;
  }  

  // starts with http://
  if (strlen($url) >= 7 && "http://" === substr($url, 0, 7)) {
    // slash-slash protocol - remove https: leaving //
    return substr($url, 5);
  }
  // starts with https://
  elseif (strlen($url) >= 8 && "https://" === substr($url, 0, 8)) {
    // slash-slash protocol - remove https: leaving //
    return substr($url, 6);
  }

  // no match, return unchanged string
  return $url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    // (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
    // preg_replace — Perform a regular expression search and replace

$array = [
    'https://lemon-kiwi.co',
    'http://lemon-kiwi.co',
    'lemon-kiwi.co',
    'www.lemon-kiwi.co',
];

foreach( $array as $value ){
    $url = preg_replace("(^https?://)", "", $value );
}
```

This code output :

```
lemon-kiwi.co
lemon-kiwi.co
lemon-kiwi.co
www.lemon-kiwi.co
```

See documentation [PHP preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)